# Is there any website that allows you to check if a position has been played before?

Tags: analysis

Is there any website that allows you to check if a position has been played before? I want to analyse a game and I want to check if it has been reached before. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Look up "Chessbase Live Database" on Google and click on the first result. You should be taken to this url:

https://database.chessbase.com/?lang=en

You just enter moves and click the magnifying glass button, causing a list of games played to show up.

Answer (score 4):

Look up "365Chess.com", which is a chess games database online. Here is the link for searching a position:

https://www.365chess.com/search_position.php

You can enter moves, import pgn, or fen positions.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out

Comment: @Lone_Ranger You are welcome! Don't hesitate to accept one of the two answers if you feel it.